# Why is my "You've earned a new privilege!" panel dimmed / somewhat greyed out?

Tags: support, profile-page, privileges

I just earned a new privilege on SO while my privilege / tag-badge progress panel was set to show tag-badge progress. I then switched it to the privilege progress to see my shiny congratulatory panel (the one that says "You've earned a new privilege!") and found that it was not shining in the glory of its full opacity, but was dimmed / somewhat greyed out. It wasn't dimmed before I switched it from showing my tag-badge progress panel.

[image: screenshot of the dimmed / somewhat greyed out privilege progress panel]

My browser console doesn't show any errors, but the element with `class="d-flex fd-column h100 d-flex fd-column jc-space-between gs16 h100 js-congrats-rep-card"` also has `style=opacity: 0.4;`.

I checked my browser extensions/userscripts, and only one of them set an `opacity` value to `0.4`, but the class selector had no overlap with the classes of the congrats rep card.

Once I refresh the page, it's normal <sup><sub>(hooray!)</sub></sup>

But... why?

I tried searching for possible duplicates with the following search in the search bar and didn't find anything that looked related: [`is:q [support] or [bug] you've earned a new privilege`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bsupport%5D+or+%5Bbug%5D+you%27ve+earned+a+new+privilege).

Comment: I wonder if its a dark mode thing to keep you from searing out your eyeballs like the Nazis in Indiana Jones and the Raiders of the Lost Ark...

Comment: Considering that you have user scripts which do not seem to interfere, have you tried disabled them to ensure they are certainly not causing that?

Comment: @nicael I can no longer go back and reproduce. After I refreshed, the panel had normal opacity, and I've since clicked the congratulatory message away. Even if I hadn't, I'd need to refresh to try with disabled extensions.